# In Swift, how to get a UIAlertAction button to stay in the enclosure when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I have a UIAlertController that has a series of buttons.  When I press the button, I want a variable to be set with a certain value which will in turn populate one of the textfields and the CoreData upon hitting the save button within the alert.

I am close but not quite there - when I press the button it will set the variable to what I want, but it immediately closes the alert.  What I want to do is use keyboard to enter the information in the 2 textfields, press the button for 'vaccination' for example to set the entryType = "vaccination" and then the user should hit save to save the record.

```
  @IBAction func buttonAddEntry(_ sender: Any) {
    var typeField = ""
    let newEntry = Vaccination(context: context)
    
    print ("Create New VAX ENTRY")
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Entry", message: "Enter Entry Details", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    
    alert.addTextField()
    alert.addTextField()
    
    let dateField = alert.textFields![0]
    dateFieldMain = dateField
    //let typeField = alert.textFields![1]
    //let commentField = alert.textFields![2]
    
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
    
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VaxViewController.datePickerValueChanged(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    
    dateFieldMain!.inputView = datePicker
    
    print ("textfield set to datepicker")
    
    
    let bt1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Vaccination", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
        (action) in
        print ("Vaccination")
        typeField = "Vaccination"
    }
    alert.addAction(bt1)
    
    let bt2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Wormer", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default){
        (action) in
        print ("Wormer")
        typeField = "Wormer"
    }
    alert.addAction(bt2)
    
    
    let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Medication", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default){
        (action) in
        print ("Medication")
        typeField = "Medication"
    }
    alert.addAction(bt3)
    
    
    
    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive) {
        (action) in return }
    alert.addAction(cancelButton)
    
    
    let alertButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { (action) in
        
        let dateField = alert.textFields![0]
        //let typeField = alert.textFields![1]
        let commentField = alert.textFields![2]
        
        //convert date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM, dd, yyyy"
        let dateConverted = dateFormatter.date(from: dateField.text!)
        
        //set the properties of the new entry
        newEntry.vaxDate1 = dateConverted
        newEntry.vaxType = typeField
        newEntry.comment = commentField.text
        newEntry.animal = self.animal
        
        try! self.context.save()
        
        self.fetchVaccinations()
        //self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    alert.addAction(alertButton)
    
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

Comment: All buttons on an alert dismiss the alert. You can't change that.  You will need to create your own view rather than using an alert controller.  Alert controllers aren't great for user data entry anyway since they are modal.

Comment: Ohhh. Thank you.